# Document containing relevant data in meta-data

Tags: standards, standardization, pdf

I find myself working with documents that need to be displayed to a user and at the same time, I need the information that they bear.

For example, you have a generated PDF document (or other "visible" format) that represents an invoice. I need to have the document to display it to the user and its information it contains in order to treat it in my system.

OCR and similar techniques are not always certain, have some overhead and as you imagine I don't want to resolve to human input.

Hence my question: **Did you ever hear of a document standard (or attempts to build on) that contains, in its meta-data, the information that it displays to the user ?**

In the format I imagine, you could have the essential information (invoice number, amount, etc ...), described in advance or not, encoded in the document and accessible progmatically.

Comment: "*[...] that contains, in its meta-data, the information that it displays to the user*. How should it be displayed? In a custom viewer? You could create a normal PDF file and add metadata to it, most PDF libraries would support that I imagine, but the question is how would you visualize the metadata to the end user?

Comment: The end user just sees the PDF and the metadata will be treated by a program. I took the example of invoices, but you can think of medical documents, official documents ... Where you need the data in your system and the "displayable" data for your user (for verification by a human, print, etc ...).

Will look into that.

Comment: PDF format can essentially contain any metadata you want. In particular the PDF Metadata entry is in ISO XMP format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZUGFeRD](https://www.ferd-net.de/startseite.html) is an electronic invoice standard that started as PDF documents with embedded XML data. This would match your question pretty well. (sorry, website is in german with incomplete english information.)

The whole development is quite convoluted, and my impression is that by trying to incorporate different approaches and formats the goal of enabling transmission of invoices with automatically processable data has become more complicated instead of simpler.

Comment: thanks ! very interesting, will be reading about the European efforts on this matter. 

Do you have an idea why it makes it more complicated ? As I understand they are trying to create a standard, not migrate or update another one. One would think that it would make adoption more simple.

Comment: As far as I understood, there have been independent developments leading to incompatible proposed standards. However, I haven't been following the development closely. You may want to have a look at the different versions of the standard.